# i create a iframe using jquery how to set its height according to content inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('.accordion').html('<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>');
});
```

please help about this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add onload="resizeIframe(this)" in your iframe and add  resizeIframe() to your .js file

```
     <script>
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
     }
     </script>
    <iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```

Comment: thanks this works, but it can't decrease height once it increase

Comment: one more help about this ,please

Comment: i want to 10% extra height from content height

Comment: @AjayJangra This will help u <script>
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
  var tenper=  parseInt(obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight/10)
  alert(tenper)
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+tenper + 'px';
     }
     </script>

Answer (score 1):

**You can use iFrame Resizer**

This library enables the automatic resizing of the height and width of both same and cross domain iFrames to fit their contained content.

Full documentationc an be found here, is very usefull:
[**github documentation for iFrame Resizer**](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)

**INCLUDE THIS SCRIPT TO YOUR PAGE**

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/master/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

**SAMPLE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('.accordion').html('<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame"></iframe>');

    iFrameResize({log:true}, '#myFrame');
});
```

Comment: @AjayJangra try updated code please from SAMPLE section

Comment: @AjayJangra as well pelase copy one more time the script from INCLUDE THIS SCRIPT TO YOUR PAGE section, i was missing this one ">"

Comment: the height not according to content , very less height appear from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css()` to set the height of that element. Hence you need to pass the id of current attribute like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
      $('.accordion').html('<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myFrame" onload="setHeight(this)"></iframe>');
   })

  function setHeight(content){
     $('#'+content.id).css('height', '100'+'px');// Whatever size you want.
  }

});
```

Comment: height not according to content, only about 50% height display

Comment: @AjayJangra try my solution with iframe resizer, i jsut had some spelling mistakes and was fixed, was looking long time for this issue and iframe resizer solved it for me, is working for cross domain as well